# Do I have to translate each word for my wordpress plugin to have a different language?

Tags: wordpress, translate

I have done some searching and just can't seem to find solid one.

Do I really have to translate each word to a different language if I want my wordpress plugin to show a different language like german or spanish for example.

I'm aware how to setup everything and using the poedit method, but it appears it is up to me to supply the translation for each word. Does anyone know an easier way, besides using a plugin to translate the site.

Comment: Well someone has to do the translation. If it's not you, then it must be someone else. Machine translation is not yet at the point where it would produce acceptable quality.

Comment: I hear ya, just seems in this age that would be possible, just considering google translation is in effect. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You can install GlotPress and gather contributors to work online in GP.

Comment: Now that's an answer, thanks @brasofilo